# SQL Query to Display Count of Total

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I've got a very complex query that joins eight (8) different tables.

For the sake of this question, though, I'll simplify it with this type of structure:

```
create table table1(PacketID int, RequestID int, EmpID int, PartNo varchar(20))

insert into table1 values
 (1 , 1, 132, 'abc123'),
 (1 , 2, 132, 'abc456'),
 (1 , 3, 132, 'def123'),
 (1 , 4, 132, 'def456'),
 (2 , 5, 228, 'xyz123'),
 (3 , 6, 239, 'xyz321'),
 (3 , 7, 239, 'aaa000')
```

This type of table creates the following output:

```
|_P_|_R_|_Emp_|_PartNo_|
|_1_|_1_|_132_|_abc123_|
|_1_|_2_|_132_|_abc465_|
|_1_|_3_|_132_|_def123_|
|_1_|_4_|_132_|_def456_|
|_2_|_5_|_228_|_xyz123_|
|_3_|_6_|_239_|_xyz321_|
|_3_|_7_|_239_|_aaa000_|
```

I put together a fiddle of it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3ce4/1

I was told they don't really need this `PacketID` or `RequestID`, but what they do need is something that shows how many requests are in a packet and what request number of that packet needs attention.

I will still need the `PacketID` and `RequestID` values in order to make changes to the data.

So, I want to add a column to the table above to be something like this:

```
|_P_|_R_|_ReadAs_|_Emp_|_PartNo_|
|_1_|_1_|_1 of 4_|_132_|_abc123_|
|_1_|_2_|_2 of 4_|_132_|_abc465_|
|_1_|_3_|_3 of 4_|_132_|_def123_|
|_1_|_4_|_4 of 4_|_132_|_def456_|
|_2_|_5_|_1 of 1_|_228_|_xyz123_|
|_3_|_6_|_1 of 2_|_239_|_xyz321_|
|_3_|_7_|_2 of 2_|_239_|_aaa000_|
```

How exactly would I go about doing that?

If you just want to feel my pain and see the complete view defined on my SQL Server, here it is:

```
SELECT P.ID AS PacketID, R.ID AS RequestID, A.ID AS ActionID,
  EI.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + EI.LASTNAME AS Employee, P.DateStamp, 
  RQ.Description AS RequestType, L.Description AS Line, R.PartNo,
  R.Workorder, R.Qty, RZ.Description AS ReasonType, R.MTF,
  A.StatusID, S.Description AS Status, A.EmpID AS Stator, 
  A.DateStamp AS Stated
FROM dbo.Packet AS P
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Request AS R ON R.PacketID = P.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Action AS A ON R.ID = A.RequestID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Action AS A2 ON A.RequestID = A2.RequestID
         AND (A.DateStamp < A2.DateStamp OR
         A.DateStamp = A2.DateStamp AND A.RequestID < A2.RequestID)
  INNER JOIN CPAPP.AIO_Test_Results.dbo.EmployeeInfo AS EI ON A.EmpID = EI.COUNT
  INNER JOIN dbo.RequestType AS RQ ON R.RequestTypeID = RQ.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Line AS L ON R.LineID = L.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.ReasonType AS RZ ON R.ReasonTypeID = RZ.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Status AS S ON A.StatusID = S.ID
WHERE (A2.RequestID IS NULL)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than just giving you the entire answer, I'll try to explain how to create the answer yourself.

To get the consecutive sequence numbers have a look at [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). You can provide a partition by (PacketID) and an order by (RequestId). This gets you the first number you need.

To get the counts, if you were using SQL Server 2012 you could use `COUNT` with a partition. On older versions of SQL Server you will have to use a JOIN and GROUP BY or a subselect.

This query demonstrates the principles using the subselect approach:

```
SELECT
    PacketID,
    RequestID,
    EmpID,
    PartNo,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PacketID ORDER BY RequestID),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 AS T2 WHERE T1.PacketId = T2.PacketId)
FROM table1 AS T1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3ce4/8

To get the exact format you requested you just need to convert the integers to strings and concatenate them. I'll leave this for you to do, but here's a few hints.

- [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- [+ (String Concatenation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As @MarkByers mentioned, `row_number()` will be especially helpful here, and I've added a correlated subquery to get the count per Packet:

```
select PacketID, RequestID
    , cast(RowNumber as varchar(11)) + ' of ' + cast(PacketCount as varchar(11)) as ReadAs
    , EmpID, PartNo
from (
    select PacketID, RequestID, EmpID, PartNo
        , row_number() over (partition by PacketID order by RequestID) as RowNumber
        , (select count(*) from table1 where PacketID = t.PacketID) as PacketCount
    from table1 as t
) as z
```